# resharper code formatting introduces needless linebreak on starting parens

Tags: c#, resharper, code-formatting

When I have `simple wrap` enabled on `Wrap invocation arguments`, I often end up with a formatted line like:

```
string.Format(
              "example string tralala {0} {1}",
              foo, bar);
```

no combination of settings I find prevents this line break other than enabling `chop if long`. unfortunately that can be a bit of a line hog (it forcibly makes each argument take a line if a function call takes up more than your max word-wrap space).

Is there any solution to this that I am overlooking?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few settings you can use to format your code just the way you like it in `re-sharper`. in Visual Studio Go: Tools>Options>Re-sharper and click the Options button there again.

Then under the `Code Editing` section, under `c#`>`Formatting Style`. You can use one of the following settings:

- Prefer wrap before `(` in declaration\invocation
- Prefer warp after `(` in declaration\invocation
- **Or** set the `wrap` invocation argument to either  *(this is most likely the one need setting)*

  - chop always.
  - chop if too long.
  - simple wrap.

[image: My settings:]

The un-tick the `wrap long lines` all together right on top op the *line wrapping`section, will`stop-wrapping`, but you'll need to go through these setting to get it just right - or to get it to format the way you code.

Comment: I've done every combination of those I believe. Challenge: craft a `string.format` similar to the one i made. make the size of the string long enough to make the next argument linebreak. mess with all of those settings. do you find a combination that gets the result I seek? It seems silly, but I can't seem to maek it happen.

Comment: I know, you want it to do it right, what is your right margin set at?

Comment: or maybe post us a screen shot of your line wrapping settings:

Comment: disabling `wrap long lines` is like using a rocket launcher to kill a mouse. Too many benefits to lose just to fix this one minor annoyance. unfortunately changing the margin amount just moves the problem around. inevitably one has to deal with a long string and this problem will persist in any case with one as far as I can tell

Comment: would the `wrap formal parameters` if set to `simple` not work just by looking at your example? This will still wrap if your text line exceeds the margin but wont give you a wrap every time?

Answer (score 0):

In `Resharper 9`
Go to `Resharper`(from Visual Studio Menu)->`Options`->`Code Editing`->`C#`->`Formatting Style`->`Line Breaks and Wrapping`
and Uncheck `Wrap Long Line` from `Line Wrapping option`

[image]